# My javascript mobile menu only opens when double clicked.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website for my friend using just HTML/CSS3 and Vanilla JS.  Everything seems to be going OK but I can't figure out why my mobile menu only opens when I click it twice. It only does this the first time I try clicking it after refreshing the page. Once it's open I can open and close it again with one click.

Here is the relevant HTML

```
            <header id = "top-menu">
            <img id = "title-image" class = "desktop-site" src = "images/ben-the-mover-guy.png">
            <img id = "mobile-title-image" class = "mobile-site" src = "images/mobile-title-white.png">
            <h1 id = "title-text">Ben the Mover Guy</h1>
            <a id = "mobile-icon" href = "javascript:void(0);" onClick = "dropDown()"><i id = "mobile-icon-id" class = "ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
            <nav id = "icon-nav" class = "desktop-site">
                <a href = "#"><i class = "ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href = "#"><i class = "ion-android-mail"></i></a>
                <a href = "#"><i class = "ion-ios-calculator"></i></a>
            </nav>
            <nav id = "main-nav" class = "horizontal-nav desktop-site">
                <span class = "selected"><a href = "#" class = "nav-link">ABOUT</a></span>
                <a href = "#" class = "nav-link">RATES</a>
                <a href = "#" id = "link-break" class = "nav-link"> <span class = "link-break-line">PREPARING FOR</span> YOUR MOVE</a>
                <a href = "#" class = "nav-link">CONTACT</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

and Javascript

```
function dropDown() {
var x = document.getElementById("main-nav");
var y = document.getElementById("mobile-icon-id");

if (x.className === "horizontal-nav") {
    x.className = "mobile-nav";
    y.className = "ion-close-round"
} else {
    x.className = "horizontal-nav";
    y.className = "ion-navicon-round"
}
}
```

The issue is definitely not the CSS. After hitting up Inspect Element I noticed that it's not changing the class name to "mobile-nav" until the second click, so it's an issue with the JS.

I did a mock website a while ago where I used similar code and I didn't have this problem.  The only difference was that I used a div with a unordered list for the nav links instead of the '' tag.  That wouldn't have anything to do with it would it?

Comment: I'd say that your problem is `hover` ;). On mobile devices hover is a first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your js function to this and it will work..

```
function dropDown() {
  var x = document.getElementById("main-nav");
  var y = document.getElementById("mobile-icon-id");
  if (x.classList.contains("horizontal-nav")) {
      x.className = "mobile-nav";
      y.className = "ion-close-round"
  } else {
      x.className = "horizontal-nav";
      y.className = "ion-navicon-round"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is occurring is because you're checking the `className` attribute, which contains *all* classes of the element. The first time it's being checked, the value is not `horizontal-nav` -- it's `horizontal-nav desktop-site`, which causes the code in the `else` block to fire. The second time around, it *is* `horizontal-nav`, so it works correctly.

Use `x.classList.contains("horizontal-nav")`, or build/use a method to check whether `className` contains `horizontal-nav` rather than is `horizontal-nav`. jQuery's `hasClass` works perfectly for this, if you need to support older browsers.